# 301 redirect dynamic urls

Tags: php, url, dynamic, redirect, http-status-code-301

Hi how do you 301 redirect http:// www.site.com/blog/index.php?id=uu5 to http:// www.newsite.com/ in .htaccess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To do a permanent redirection of domain you can use this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: don't forget to enable mod_rewrite